# Referencing a file (module) in Typescript using AMD

Tags: javascript, typescript, amd

I am new to [Typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) and module handling. In my project I am coding in Typescript for developing a browser library. I am therefore using [AMD](http://requirejs.org/). Following is the `tsconfig.json` file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "outDir": "out",
    "module": "amd"
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/communication.ts",
    ...
  ]
}
```

File `communication.ts` is:

```
export module MyProj.DataExchange {
  export interface Communication {
    connect(uri: string): void;
    close(): void;
    status: int;
  }
}
```

#### Referencing components from other files

I want to use `Communication` in `main.ts`:

```
import communication = require('./communication');
export module MyProj {
  export class Communicator 
    implements communication.MyProj.DataExchange.Communication {
    ...
  }
}
```

I would like to avoid using the whole signature `communication.MyProj.DataExchange.Communication`. So I tried something like:

```
import communication = require('./communication').MyProj.DataExchange;
```

But it did not work.

#### My questions

I have a feeling I am doing something wrong in here. Here my questions:

- Am I doing things the way they are supposed to be done?
- How to avoid using the whole name for an imported component?
- In case you might tell me not to use `module`, I need to separate my components into namespaces. So how to correctly set namespaces in case I am doing it wrong?

Comment: Why did you put the Communication interface within a module?  Just eliminate the outer module and use communication.Communication.

Answer (score 1):

In Typescript 1.4 have been introduced [Type Aliases](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/01/16/announcing-typescript-1-4.aspx).

Your code might be adapted to use aliases like this:

```
import communication = require('./communication')
type Communication = communication.MyProj.DataExchange.Communication;
export module MyProj {
  export class Communicator 
    implements Communication {
    ...
  }
}
```